# Problem with MappedWord

Tags: gap

The setup I give here is only examplary but shows how I want to use MappedWord in diverse contexts. I have

$S$ : A finite symmetric group with generators $s_1$ and $s_2$

$H$ : a known subgroup of $S$ generated by $h_1$ and $h_2$

$G$  : a group generated by two $120 \times 120$ matrices generated by $phi$ and 
$psi$ isomorphic to $S$ with corresponding generators.

I want to transfer the generators $h_i$ expressed as words in $s_i$ to $G$ using following code:

```
gap> F := FreeGroup("a","b");;
gap> AssignGeneratorVariables(F);;
#I  Assigned the global variables [ a, b ]
gap> epi := EpimorphismFromFreeGroup(S:names := ["a","b"]);;
gap> wrd := PreImagesRepresentative(epi, (1,4)(2,5));
a*b^-1*a*b*a^-2*(a^-1*b^-1)^2*a^-2
gap> sigma := MappedWord(wrd,[a,b],[phi, psi]);
Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethod
...
gap> #But this works if I type in the word by hand (or ctrl+C, ctrl+V):
gap> sigma := MappedWord(a*b^-1*a*b*a^-2*(a^-1*b^-1)^2*a^-2,[a,b],[phi,psi]);;
```

This is ok if I work in a manual session but I don't know how to use MappedWord this way in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `EpimorphismFromFreeGroup`, GAP creates a *new* free group, regardless how the generators are called.  You can verify this by testing

```
FamilyObj(a)=FamilyObj(wrd);
```

which will return `false`.

So what you should do is to ensure the generators are of the source of `epi`, either by reordering the commands and changing `F`:

```
gap> epi := EpimorphismFromFreeGroup(S:names := ["a","b"]);;
gap> F := Source(epi);
gap> AssignGeneratorVariables(F);;
```

or make `epi` a map from `F`:

```
epi:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(F,S,[a,b],GeneratorsOfGroup(S));
```

Then everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps me enormously. Maybe I should study chapter 13 of the reference manual a bit more thoroughly..